# What is the contemporary method of announcing large sections of existing publications?

Tags: fiction, citations

I am building out an article published in 1896, wrapping a whole novel series around it. I will be switching back and forth between said article and my additions, with Article: Pt. 1, Novel dialogue, Article, Pt. 2, Novel dialogue, etc.

Each article portion forms its own chapter, followed by a chapter of my own.

This query concerns chapter headings for the published content. Let me show you how Bram Stoker did it in Dracula:

> ### Chapter VII
>
> #### Cutting from “The Dailygraph,” 8 August
>
> (*Pasted in Mina Murray's Journal*)
>
> From a correspondent.
> *Whitby*.
>
> One of the greatest and suddenest storms on record has just been
> experienced here, with results both strange and unique.

([image of page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2zx7.png))

He credited “The Dailygraph,” with a date, included that it was a cutting, pasted into Mina’s journal, from a Correspondent. (And I don’t know what *Whitby.* refers to here.

This was how it was done in 1897.

There is a difference here, in that Stoker’s *Dailygraph* publication is fictitious, where I am including cuttings of a real published circular from 1896.

First, I have already credited the article author in my book, as a matter of propriety. Now I need to introduce an entire chapter copied from this work.

The work I will be interleaving is from the periodical below:

- Magazine Title: The Outlook
- Publication date: 3 Oct, 1896
- Article title: The Ship’s Steward
- Article author: Guatav Kobbé

Like Dracula, a chapter will be nothing more than the first several paragraphs of this prior work.

Also like Stoker, this will be “found footage” of some sort (maybe a cutting or the paper is picked up by a character. Undecided as yet)

### Is there a convention for announcing large blocks of prior published epistolary content?

An MLA citation will just look really weird and probably be unreadable to the general public.

Comment: *"And I don’t know what Whitby. refers to here."* From the content of the page, it looks like it's a location, probably https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitby

Comment: @towr I just spotted that as well, so typical news article header info with the year and fictitious journalist blanked out.

Comment: I don't think the year and journalist are blanked out. I think the cutting only start after "(Pasted in ..)", so there is no date in the actually cutting. And "from the correspondent" might just be how it was written in the journal, like in https://paperspast.natlib.govt.nz/newspapers/TC18860716.2.5

Comment: @towr Ah, good find. I suppose maybe journalists had to earn their stripes before getting their name in print, as a sort of promotion; or a publication kept a safe distance from a new employee's name until they were "vested." Interesting. I see this novel (and Stoker) in a new light.